# Why would an integer property sometimes return a 0?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, properties, timer

[Edit: I realized that the parameter that is failing is actually a double and not an integer. None of the integer timers fail according to the logs. Most of the timers and parameters are integers, but not all. Doubles are not atomic and the lack of locking may be the issue after all.]

I have an application that uses a class that contains properties for configurable values. Most of the properties being used in the app are derived. The values are set at start up and not changed while the main portion of the application is running.

```
private int _TimerInterval;
public int TimerInterval { get { return _TimerInterval; } }

private int _Factor1;
public int Factor1 { 
  set { 
    _Factor1 = value;
    _TimerInterval = _Factor1 * _Factor2;
  }
  get { return _Factor1; }
}

private int _Factor2;
public int Factor2 { 
  set { 
    _Factor2 = value;
    _TimerInterval = _Factor1 * _Factor2;
  }
  get { return _Factor2; }
}
```

I find that very rarely the value returned is apparently zero because of an exception.

```
Exception Message: '0' is not a valid value for 'Interval'. 'Interval' must be   greater than 0.
Exception Target Site: set_Interval
```

The calling code looks lime this:

```
exitTimer.Interval = _config.TimerInterval;
```

The program is multi-threaded but the call to the individual property is only used in one thread. Other properties of the class are called in other threads. I do see the issue on other timers with similar properties.

If I trap the exception and retry the assignment it works.

Could there be something happening at my timer that would cause the execption other than the property returning zero?

**Update #1 - More code was requested**

Each field is defined as a `cfXXX` (Configuration Field) constant. This ensures we don't misspell the field names. A corresponding default value for each property is defined as `DefXXX`. The `PareseXXX` functions (`ParseInt` in this sample) accepts the string value from the configuration lookup and converts it to the corresponding value type or the provided default if it fails. Failure would be from a missing XML record (new configuration option) or one that was incorrectly edited.

Code to load initial configuration data:

```
// Main Form
public fMain()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  config = new ConfigData();
  config.LoadConfig();
  // Other initializations
}

//ConfigData Class

// XML config field names
private const string cfFactor1 = "Factor1";
private const string cfFactor1 = "Factor2";
private const string cfFactor3 = "Factor3";
private const string cfFactor4 = "Factor4";

//Default values
private const int DefFactor1 = 1;
private const int DefFactor2 = 50;
private const int DefFactor3 = 1;
private const int DefFactor4 = 25;

public void LoadConfig()
{
  Factor1 = ParseInt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[cfFactor1], DefFactor1);
  Factor2 = ParseInt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[cfFactor2], DefFactor2);
  Factor3 = ParseInt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[cfFactor3], DefFactor3);
  Factor4 = ParseInt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[cfFactor4], DefFactor4);
}

int ParseInt(string numberString, int aDefault = 0)
{
  int result;
  if (!int.TryParse(numberString, out result)) {
    result = aDefault;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: how are you setting `Factor1` and `Factor2`?

Comment: "The program is multi-threaded..."  <-- Well there's your problem.

Comment: Clearly the _config.TimerInterval property is 0.  That's a typical sign of a *threading race*, allowing the thread to start *before* _config is fully initialized.  And of course it could mean that your config is just bad or missing.

Comment: @DanielA.White - At start up the configuration file is loaded (myApp.exe.config) and the values are set at that time. After that the Factors are no longer used.

Comment: @RichShealer please provide more code.

Comment: @HansPassant - I would agree, but those values were set at least minutes, typically hours or days before and not changed. There is a lot of preparation being done elsewhere before they can start running.

Comment: That's accidental synchronization.  It is never ever a substitute for real synchronization.

Comment: @HansPassant - Since I do have an issue there must be a reason and I can create a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` for each property, but it seemed to be a lot of overhead for this scenario. I have about 60 properties overall.

Comment: You normally only care that _config is initialized.  If this matters for every single property of that class then, yes, you do have bigger problems and a lot more ways to induce a threading race.

Comment: I hope your *posted* LoadConfig contains a typo: 4x assignment to "Factor1"?

Comment: @HansKesting - Thanks fixed. I shortened the list of fields and simplified the names for this example. The actual names have less meaning in a generic example.

Comment: @HansPassant - It apparently does matter, unless the problem is in the timer itself. I'm thinking that maybe it expires right when I assign to it. It's only the timer assignments that are failing.

Comment: Can't you just initialize the config complete, and only then publish a reference to it? After publishing a reference, never modify it. That makes it automatically safe.

Comment: @usr - Pardon my ignorance.  What do you mean by publish an reference? I assume you don't mean pass the instance as a reference to the other classes. That is what I do now.

Comment: @RichShealer yes, I meant passing the reference around. You must be doing that now, because otherwise no such threading bug would be possible. Try adding locks around every property access including gets. Does that get rid of the problem? That proves that it is a threading problem.

Comment: Assuming this is still a problem, I agree with @Hans-Passant: looks like a threading race. Anyway there's not enough info here to help you - do `exitTimer` and `config` (or is it `_config`?) belong to fMain or some other class? How about posting the exception stack trace?

Comment: If your properties are set on startup - that is, *guaranteed* set to correct values before any other code runs, and nothing else modifies the values of the properties - then your problem is not a race condition. There is nothing thread-related that will cause repeated property `get`s to return a different value, except for modifying the value of that property. I would suspect there's some code you've not posted that is modifying `_TimerInterval`...

Comment: Are you calling `LoadConfig` more than once from different threads? You could have a race condition there, if so...

Comment: @DanPuzey - No. It is loaded once. I would like to be able to in the future modify it so that I can make changes on the fly but currently I do not.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the last line of `LoadConfig` (the closing brace)? Confirm that a) it's called exactly once and b) the value of `_TimerInterval` is correctly set?  And can you confirm that absolutely nothing outside of that method changes the value of `_TimerInterval`?

Comment: @groverboy - the variable is stored as _config in the classes that have had it passed at creation.

Comment: I may just find every instance of the timers and try/catch the exception and then retry it. As I said before this may be an issue with the timers doing something odd.

Comment: Between your initial code posting and the update, there are two different config fields/variables - `config` and `_config` - is that just an anonymization artifact of editing into your post, or are they in fact two separate locations? If the latter, how are they coordinated?

Comment: @DanPuzey - I will add some logging so that it logs each time it is called. Then I will push it out to the customer and let them run it. It will take a day or two to get feedback.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Please understand this is a simplified version of code. I have about 20 timer values. The class that creates config data initially has a variable named config. In other classes where it was passed the variable where it is stored in is called _config. If it is passed in a method the parameter name is "config".

Comment: I doubt that you'll find an issue with the timers; I've seen this exception and it was due to a coding error. The fMain constructor can't be the startup code for an app, this is a form class. If you move the initialization of `config` to the Main function this is one way to be sure it is fully initialized before starting any threads. Btw did you check the call stack when the exception came up?

Comment: @groverboy - Okay your prodding about the stack showed me something that I was too blind to see. There are two timer types that I deal with and one of them actually uses a double as a timer parameter. Looking at the recent logs show the timer errors are for a double which is not atomic and is probably the root issue after all that locking will fix. <hangs head> I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the premise was wrong. The properties that failed were actually floats and not integers. Embarrassing. As expected adding locks to the properties for those items cured the problem. The integer timers never failed.

I would have just deleted the question at this point, but it already has answers. So let it be a lesson on double checking assumptions.

Comment: +1 for confirming the required fix and what you learned. Useful feedback for me, at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign these factors one time for each instance, before the instance is used...  Do that in a constructor.

If you want to assign these factors one time for the type, before any instances are created... Do that in a static constructor.

Don't share mutable instances between threads.

Answer (score 0):

_TimerInterval is 0 when just Factor1 or Factor2 is set.

x * 0 = 0

Comment: True, but not in this case.

Comment: Your LoadConfig function just set Factor1

Comment: Yes it did - cut and paste typo when I was simplifying the names. Sorry.

Comment: Then just synchronize all calls to your "config" variable, then your problem should go. :)