# What is a best practice for making a class's properties thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, properties, thread-safety

[Edit: It looks like the original question involved a double and not an integer. So I think this question stands if we change the integer to a double.]

I have rare issue with reading integer properties from a class used in multiple threads that sometimes returns a zero value. The values are not changed after initialization.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095042/why-would-an-integer-property-sometimes-return-a-0) addresses that. The consensus is that even though I'm accessing an integer I need to synchronize the properties. (Some of the original answers have been deleted). I haven't chosen an answer there because I have not resolved my issue yet.

So I’ve done some research on this and I’m not sure which of .Net 4’s locking mechanisms to use or if the locks should be outside the class itself.

This is what I thought about using:

```
  public class ConfigInfo
  {
    private readonly object TimerIntervalLocker = new object();
    private int _TimerInterval;
    public int TimerInterval
    {
      get
      {
        lock (TimerIntervalLocker) {
          return _TimerInterval;
        }
      }
    }

    private int _Factor1;
    public int Factor1
    {
      set
      {
        lock (TimerIntervalLocker) {
          _Factor1 = value;
          _TimerInterval = _Factor1 * _Factor2;
        }
      }
      get
      {
        lock (TimerIntervalLocker) {
          return _Factor1;
        }
      }
    }

    private int _Factor2;
    public int Factor2
    {
      set
      {
        lock (TimerIntervalLocker) {
          _Factor2 = value;
          _TimerInterval = _Factor1 * _Factor2;
        }
      }
      get
      {
        lock (TimerIntervalLocker) {
          return _Factor2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But I’ve read that this is horribly slow.

Another alternative is to lock the instance of `ConfigData` on the user side but that seems to be a lot of work. Another alternative I’ve seen is `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` but I think Lock is the same thing with less syntax.

> So what is a best practice for making a class's properties thread
>   safe?

Comment: If you do not mutate state after initialization (initialization being defined as before the class is consumed by other threads) then your code would already be perfectly threadsafe without any locks.

Comment: It is better to develop such design that avoids such situations. I would look into design of the whole thing first.

Comment: This isn't going to solve the problem you're talking about - as Kirk suggests, your code is *already* threadsafe (based on the sample in your other question, this is definitely the case). I would suggest that you persevere with your first question: the problem is *not* what you suggest it is - your property is not *randomly* returning a zero just because you're accessing it from multiple threads. (From the code you posted, the only way you'd get a zero is if you requested a value before initialisation was complete, but that's a comment for the other question.)

Comment: If `TimerInterval` is not allowed to be zero, why do you allow the default construction to set it to zero? Also, why do you not check that `value` is non-zero in the setters for `Factor` and `Factor2`? From your previous question, it looks like your bug is caused by either attempting to use `TimerInterval` before both factors are set to non-zero, or because something is setting one of the factors to zero.

Comment: @DanPuzey I think the code is NOT threadsafe without the locks - one thread could be setting `Factor1` while another is setting `Factor2` which could result in an incorrect value for `ThreadInterval` because it is being computed from both factors.

Comment: @KirkWoll-That's what I thought but the problem persists. Randomly the value is read as a zero. I've thrown in tests so that if it is zero, sleep(1) and try again an it usually works.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: sorry, I should have been more explicit. you're absolutely right - the posted code is not threadsafe, but the described usage is threadsafe (based on the code in the linked question).

Comment: @RichShealer If `TimerInterval` is ever zero, there are only two possibilities: (1) You are accessing it before the two factors have both been set to nonzero values, or (2) Something is setting one or both of the factors to zero. There's no other possibility (other than the very unlikely one that the factors are set to values which when multiplied together overflow in a way that results in zero)

Comment: If the values never change, then why are there public setters?

Comment: @DannyVarod - There are public setters so that they can be set initially by a class that reads the configuration data.

Comment: @RichShealer That's not a good case for public setters - it sounds like you need readonly fields set in the constructor.

Comment: @RichShealer In that case, why don't you set them in the constructor and remove the setters?

Comment: @MatthewWatson - I'd agree that the initialization might have failed if the values weren't working up until the exception happens minutes or hours after startup.

Comment: "I've read that this is horribly slow" -- don't do performance analysis by reading about someone else's code. Do performance analysis by running the code! An uncontended lock is about 10-100 nanoseconds. A contended lock is arbitrarily slow. The right solution is almost always to refactor your program to avoid the contention, and take the 10-100 ns hit.

Comment: That said, the description of your program doesn't match the problem you are describing. There's a setter being called somewhere that you don't know about and that's where the bug is. If the intention is that the fields be set once then set them in the constructor, make the fields readonly, and you're done.

Comment: Try to see if you can create a toy example that reproduces the behavior. By doing so you'll either (1) find your bug, or (2) make a program small enough that you can post the complete program here and people can help you analyze it.

Comment: @EricLippert - I've never seen it happen in simulation. Only infrequently on the factory floor when they are running production. I have some ideas and will attempt to sort it out some more and post back.

Comment: @EricLippert - I will log each access to the setter and see if something is happening that is unexpected. I could then rework the code to remove them.

Comment: @EricLippert - The horribly slow part is part of why I'm asking this question to make sure this method hasn't been deprecated in favor of a newer technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. Using lock can be slow since it uses operating system resources, if the properties' complexity is low, then spin lock (or interlocked.compareexchange) will be faster.

b. You have to make sure that a thread won't enter a lock and via a call from one property to another get locked out. - If this can happen (non currently an issue in your code), you'll need to make the lock thread or task sensitive.

Edit:

If the object is supposed to be set during initialization and never changed, make it immutable (like .NET strings are). Remove all the public setters and provide a constructor with parameters for defining the initial state and perhaps additional methods/operators for creating a new instance with a modified state (e.g. var newString = "Old string" + " was modified.";).

Comment: "Using lock is slow" - this is very, very difficult to measure since it depends on a lot of non-deterministic factors.

Comment: @BryanCrosby true, but I didn't want to get into a long theory lecture. I'll reword this.

Answer (score 1):

If the values never change, it would be easier to just make a copy of that instance and pass each thread an instance of it's own. No locking required at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rewrite your `ConfigInfo` class to look like this; then you can't get overflow or threading problems:

```
public sealed class ConfigInfo
{
    public ConfigInfo(int factor1, int factor2)
    {
        if (factor1 <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("factor1");

        if (factor2 <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("factor2");

        _factor1 = factor1;
        _factor2 = factor2;

        checked
        {
            _timerInterval = _factor1*_factor2;
        }
    }

    public int TimerInterval
    {
        get
        {
            return _timerInterval;
        }
    }

    public int Factor1
    {
        get
        {
            return _factor1;
        }
    }

    public int Factor2
    {
        get
        {
            return _factor2;
        }
    }

    private readonly int _factor1;
    private readonly int _factor2;
    private readonly int _timerInterval;
}
```

Note that I'm using `checked` to detect overflow problems.

Otherwise some values will give incorrect results.

For example, `57344 * 524288` will give zero in unchecked integer arithmetic (and there's very many other pairs of values that will give zero, and even more that will give a negative result or a positive value that "seems" correct).

Answer (score 0):

It is best, as mentioned in the comments, to make the properties *readonly*. I thought about the following possibility:

```
public class ConfigInfo
{
    private class IntervalHolder
    {
        public static readonly IntervalHolder Empty = new IntervalHolder();

        private readonly int _factor1;
        private readonly int _factor2;
        private readonly int _interval;

        private IntervalHolder()
        {
        }

        private IntervalHolder(int factor1, int factor2)
        {
            _factor1 = factor1;
            _factor2 = factor2;
            _interval = _factor1*_factor2;
        }

        public IntervalHolder WithFactor1(int factor1)
        {
            return new IntervalHolder(factor1, _factor2);
        }

        public IntervalHolder WithFactor2(int factor2)
        {
            return new IntervalHolder(_factor1, factor2);
        }

        public int Factor1
        {
            get { return _factor1; }
        }

        public int Factor2
        {
            get { return _factor2; }
        }

        public int Interval
        {
            get { return _interval; }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var otherHolder = obj as IntervalHolder;
            return 
                otherHolder != null &&
                otherHolder._factor1 == _factor1 &&
                otherHolder._factor2 == _factor2;
        }
    }

    private IntervalHolder _intervalHolder = IntervalHolder.Empty;

    public int TimerInterval
    {
        get { return _intervalHolder.Interval; }
    }

    private void UpdateHolder(Func<IntervalHolder, IntervalHolder> update)
    {
        IntervalHolder oldValue, newValue;
        do
        {
            oldValue = _intervalHolder;
            newValue = update(oldValue);

        } while (!oldValue.Equals(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _intervalHolder, newValue, oldValue)));
    }

    public int Factor1
    {
        set { UpdateHolder(holder => holder.WithFactor1(value)); }
        get { return _intervalHolder.Factor1; }
    }

    public int Factor2
    {
        set { UpdateHolder(holder => holder.WithFactor2(value)); }
        get { return _intervalHolder.Factor2; }
    }
}
```

This way, your *TimerInterval* value is always in sync with its factors. The only problem is when some thread reads one of the properties while another writes them from outside the *ConfigInfo*. The first one could get wrong value and I don't see any way to solve this without introducing a single lock root. The question is whether read operations are critical.